# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "io2d" (Windows)

Tags: c++, cmake

I am newbie in using C++ and I have hard times to compile the io2d with CMake. I am currently using Windows, and I have used **vcpkg** to download the **io2d** packages, **cairo** packages and **graphicsmagick** packages. Everything are downloaded by both x64 and x86 windows.

The way I follow through on the installation work is from the **Buildings Steps** in **Cairo/Win32 on Windows**:
https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl/blob/master/BUILDING.md

However, when I build with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=c:/source/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows" ..\.` , it appears the following error. And I have looked for online but seems cannot find a solution with windows system.

Happy to get any opinions and help on this issue.

```
PS C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\桌面\Udacity\CppND-Route-Planning-Project\P0267_RefImpl\Debug> cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=c:/source/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows" ..\.
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
Default IO2D backend was not specified, choosing automatically...
Found Windows, using CAIRO_WIN32.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find Cairo (missing: CAIRO_INCLUDE_DIRS CAIRO_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:577 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindCairo.cmake:102 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/cairo/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

---

I have tried another way to compile, but also does not work which yield to another problem. The location of my entire project folder is in the following address: **C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\桌面\Udacity\CppND-Route-Planning-Project**.

When I tried to build the project, firstly I `cd` to the address above.

Then use `mkdir build` and `cd build`

Then run `cmake ..`

But, it appears the error code in finding the io2d configuration files. I have no idea how to let CMake to find the required files. The error is located as belows:

```
PS C:\Users\samue\OneDrive\桌面\Udacity\CppND-Route-Planning-Project\build> cmake ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
CMake Error at C:/source/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:622 (_find_package):
  By not providing "Findio2d.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "io2d", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "io2d" with any of
  the following names:

    io2dConfig.cmake
    io2d-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "io2d" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "io2d_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "io2d"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: looking through the tutorial in the link you post, I don't see where you should run `cmake ..`. Could you please state the steps you took and where it failed?

Comment: Sorry I have quoted wrongly for the error code, when I run the cmake code above, it appears to cannot find the Cairo, but I have installed the Cairo package already, don't know why the problem occured

Comment: I've followed the steps in your link, to try to reproduce your issue, but i get `-- Found Cairo: C:/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include/cairo (found version "1.16.0")` etc... so it works for me... clean everything and try again?

Comment: Thank you for the advice and I tried to reinstall vcpkg again and follow the steps, it can find the Cairo but raise other error: 
`CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.`

Comment: The error code exceeds the maximum wordings, remaining is:
`Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CHARSET_LIB
    linked by target "io2d_cairo_win32" in directory C:/Users/samue/OneDrive/桌面/Udacity/CppND-Route-Planning-Project/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/P0267_RefImpl/cairo/win32

EXPAT_LIB
    linked by target "io2d_cairo_win32" in directory ...

ICONV_LIB
    linked by target "io2d_cairo_win32" in directory ...
`

Comment: yes, I had the same issues. But that's a different issue. I don't have all the answers. You could always check [the issues page](https://github.com/cpp-io2d/P0267_RefImpl/issues) see if somebody had the same problems. Else open a new issue.